# CakePHP Authentication Middleware not called

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-4.x

I used AuthComponent a lot but am new to AuthenticationMiddleware.  I follow almost exactly https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html except the username field is username instead of email.  But when I try to get a page requiring authentication, Cake throws UnauthenticatedException in AuthenticationComponent::doIdentityCheck().  This can be understood because Cake should have redirected me to /users/login, which it did not.  I tried

```
$service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
   'loginUrl' => '/users/login' // case 1
   // or case 2 'loginUrl' => \Cake\Routing\Router::url('/users/login'),
   // or case 3 omit this to use the default
```

In all the above cases Cakes throws UnauthenticatedException with the message:

**No identity found. You can skip this check by configuring requireIdentity to be false.**

Also http://localhost:8765/users/login leads me to the correct page, also I can see the list of users by http://localhost:8765/users/ if I allow unauthenticated as this:

```
// UsersController.php
public function initialize() : void {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->Authentication->allowUnauthenticated(['index', 'login']);
}
```

My environment: CakePHP 4.0, authentication plugin 2.0.  Is there a way to verify that AuthenticationMiddleware has indeed been set up and added to the middleware queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd get a different error if the middleware didn't ran, one that would complain about the `authentication` attribute missing on the request object.

You need to configure the `unauthenticatedRedirect` option on the service object in order for redirects being issued for unauthenticated requests, without that option being configured you'll receive exceptions instead. Additionally you may need to set the `queryParam` option (that's the query string parameter that will hold the initially accessed URL) if you want to be able to redirect users after successfully logging in.

```php
$service->setConfig([
    'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/users/login',
    'queryParam' => 'redirect',
]);
```

<strike>That seems to be missing from the docs, it's only [**mentioned in the migration notes**](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/migration-from-the-authcomponent.html#migrating-unauthenticated-redirects). You may want to open an issue for that [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/).</strike> The quickstart guide example has been updated to include the redirect configuration.